# Module not loading in the administration and also not showingin the menu in shopware

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6, shopware5

**
The Module Code**

```
import enGB from "./snippets/en-GB.json";
import deDE from "./snippets/de-DE.json";
import "./page/ingredients-list";

Shopware.Module.register('ingredients', {
    type: 'plugin',
    name: 'Example',
    title: 'ingredients.general.mainMenuItemGeneral',
    description: 'ingredients.general.descriptionTextModule',
    color: '#ff3d58',
    icon: 'regular-whatsapp',
    snippets: {
        'en-GB': enGB,
        'de-DE': deDE
    },
    routes: {
        list: {
            component: 'ingredient-list-page',
            path: 'ingredients'
        }
    },
    navigation: [{
        id: 'swag-custommodule-list',
        label: 'ingredients.listIngredients',
        color: '#ff3d58',
        path: 'ingredients.list',
        icon: 'regular-whatsapp',
        parent: 'sw-catalogue',
        position: 100
    }],
    settingsItem: [{
        group: 'plugin',
        to: 'swag.plugin.list',
        icon: 'default-object-rocket',
        name: 'swag-example.general.mainMenuItemGeneral'
    }],
    created() {
        console.log("Moduleeeeeeeeeeeeeee Created");
    }
})
```

[This is The Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jUUo.png)

I did an Administration build and i cleared the cache too but still nothing is showing up in the administration

I am expecting this module to be created and to ne shown as a menu entry in the administration under the catalogue section

Answer (score 1):

The technical name of your module has to be in the format `{{vendor}}-{{name}}`. This is to prevent multiple developers choosing identical names for their modules. For the vendor choose a rather short prefix that should uniquely represent you.

Registering the module should then work like this:

```js
Shopware.Module.register('foo-ingredients', {
    // ...
    routes: {
        list: {
            component: 'foo-ingredient-list-page',
            path: 'ingredients',
        },
    },
    navigation: [{
        label: 'ingredients.listIngredients',
        color: '#ff3d58',
        path: 'foo.ingredients.list', // in paths separate vendor prefix by dot
        icon: 'regular-whatsapp',
        parent: 'sw-catalogue',
        position: 100,
    }],
})
```

Note that you should also prepend all the names of your components with your vendor prefix.

Comment: i did exactly what you told me to do but now i get this error after building the administration :

Erroneous area:
1: $border-radius-default / 2
^..^
    at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/static/css/swag-extension-store.css:9:113
    at Object.parseError (/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/postcss-calc/dist/parser.js:1200:15)
    at Object.lexer_parseError [as parseError] (/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/postcss-calc/dist/parser.js:2333:44

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the issue described in the question and definitely wasn't caused by changing the module name. There's something weird going on  with your installation if vendor files include invalid scss. Maybe consider a re-install with composer.

Comment: This is a remarkable answer! it got my problem solved, thank you!